# How to group list of objects, which contains another list?

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

I have a class with these properties:

```
public string FirstName { get; set; }
public string LastName { get; set; }
public int ID { get; set; }
public GradeLevel Year;
public List<int> ExamScores;
```

And a method:

```
protected static List<Student> students = new List<Student>
{
    new Student {FirstName = "Terry", LastName = "Adams", ID = 120, 
        Year = GradeLevel.SecondYear, 
        ExamScores = new List<int>{ 99, 82, 81, 92}},
    new Student {FirstName = "Fadi", LastName = "Fakhouri", ID = 116, 
        Year = GradeLevel.ThirdYear,
        ExamScores = new List<int>{ 99, 81, 90, 94}},
    new Student {FirstName = "Hanying", LastName = "Feng", ID = 117, 
        Year = GradeLevel.FirstYear, 
        ExamScores = new List<int>{ 90, 94, 81, 82}},
}
```

Next step:

```
public void GroupByMark()
{
    students.ForEach(mark =>
    {
        var queryNumericRange =
            from student in students
            group new {student.FirstName, student.LastName} by mark
            into percentGroup
            orderby percentGroup.Key
            select percentGroup;
        foreach (var studentGroup in queryNumericRange)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Key: {0}", (studentGroup.Key));
            foreach (var item in studentGroup)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\t{0}, {1}", item.LastName, item.FirstName);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Result:

```
key: test.StudentClass+Student
    Adams, Terry
    Fakhouri, Fadi
    Feng, Hanying

key: test.StudentClass+Student
    Adams, Terry
    Fakhouri, Fadi
    Feng, Hanying

key: test.StudentClass+Student
    Adams, Terry
    Fakhouri, Fadi
    Feng, Hanying
```

Desired result:

```
key: 99
    Adams, Terry
    Fakhouri, Fadi

key: 82
    Adams, Terry
    Feng, Hanying

key: 81
    Adams, Terry
    Fakhouri, Fadi

key: 92
    Adams, Terry

key: 90
    Fakhouri, Fadi
    Feng, Hanying

key: 94
    Fakhouri, Fadi
    Feng, Hanying
```

So, for each mark I would like to display list of students, who received that particular mark. Do you have any ideas how to do it?

Comment: Just to clarify, you definitely want each student occurring four times, once for each mark received? Possibly multiple times for the same mark, if they received it in multiple exams?

Comment: Does `Feng, Hanying` have a score of 94? You seem to have a mistake?

Comment: @JonSkeet, yes that's what I want.

Comment: @YacoubMassad, yes, I made a mistake. Just wanted to underline, that I want to have list of student for each mark.

Comment: Can you fix the desired output? Also, can you change the input so that one student has the same mark twice and also show the corresponding change in desired output? For example `{ 90, 90, 81, 82}`.

Answer (score 1):

Yop can use `SelectMany` to flatten the list and then group by exam scores like this:-

```
var queryNumericRange = students.SelectMany(x => x.ExamScores, (stuObj, scores) => new
             {
                 StudentName = String.Format("{0},{1}",stuObj.LastName,stuObj.FirstName),
                 ExamScores = scores
             })
             .GroupBy(x => x.ExamScores)
             .Select(x => new
                  {
                      Key = x.Key,
                      StudentNames = x.Select(s => s.StudentName).ToList()
                  });
```

[Working Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/CUqEAa)

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do it:

```
var results = students
    .SelectMany(score => score.ExamScores) //get all scores from all students
    .Distinct() //remove duplicate scores
    .Select(score => //for each score create a new anonymous object
        new
        {
            Score = score, //That contains the score itself
            Students = students //And the students that have such score
                .Where(student => student.ExamScores.Contains(score)).ToList()
        })
    .ToList();
```

Or like this if you just care about the student names:

```
var results = students
    .SelectMany(score => score.ExamScores)
    .Distinct()
    .Select(score =>
        new
        {
            Score = score,
            Students = students
                .Where(student => student.ExamScores.Contains(score))
                .Select(student => student.LastName + ", " + student.FirstName)
                .ToList()
        })
    .ToList();
```

Here is how you can loop through the results in the later case:

```
foreach (var result in results)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Score: " + result.Score);

    foreach (var student in result.Students)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(student);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to create a sequence of student/mark pairs, and then group by the mark:

```
var studentsByMark = from student in students
                     from mark in student.ExamScores
                     group student by mark;
foreach (var group in studentsByMark)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}:", group.Key); // Mark
    foreach (var student in group)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", student.LastName, student.FirstName);
    }
}
```